# tfs - Can Team Foundation Server be used outside of Visual Studio with TFVC?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We're looking to have various kinds of development in our VCS (currently moving away from PVCS): Java, PHP, Oracle Forms & Reports, etc, with the possibility of .NET development in our VCS in the future (adding existing projects from other teams). It seems TFS is built for Visual Studio development and the clients for TFS outside of Visual Studio are not very mature (except Team Explorer).

Do many teams use TFS with TFVC for development occurring outside of Visual Studio?

We're leaning toward Git, yet a couple other teams of ours (that we may share a VCS in the future with) are heavy Microsoft shops. They're leaning toward TFS. I know we can all use TFS with both Git and TFVC behind the scenes, but it seems better to have us all on the same VCS if we're all in TFS so the workflows are similar, regardless of the project. If TFVC can work for us, that seems the best candidate.

Another small question is, does TFS keep a list of all changes (add/delete/modify) made in a working directory? I read that 2010 does not. I setup a TFS trial server, but haven't had the chance to test yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can work outside of Visual Studio, if you don't mind a command line interface - the [command-line tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc31bk2e.aspx) allows you to do almost everything that can be done from the IDE's graphical UI, as well as extra admin features that aren't available in the GUI. It's not pretty but it works fine.

Even better for day to day use, there is also a Window Shell Extension included in the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) which allows you to manage source controlled files in file explorer windows - right click a file and you can check it in/out, undo checkout, rename/move or delete it in source control.

To work with TFS you create a Workspace (a mapping of folders on the server to local folders on your PC). TFS copies the source code to this workspace, and remembers what you have checked out and keeps a local list of "pending changes" as you work on code. This (or part thereof) can then be checked back in to the server when your work is completed.

Comment: Thank you Jason. This is very helpful. On the second question, we're currently looking at a new VCS because PVCS is lacking in this area (this has been confirmed with Serena support).The development we've traditionally done works fine with this workflow because we knew what files we wanted to change. In our new environment, however, this isn't possible. Via the IDE, many files can change unawares to us. So, in a new VCS, it's very important we have a way to list all files that have been added, changed or deleted and selectively add them to a commit. Does TFS do this, and if so does itdoitwell?

Comment: Something similar to this: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_kJkoNF_3MnM/RavKH0lJbaI/AAAAAAAAAB0/KjkFnbTm0a8/s1600-h/commit-dialog.png. Something I found that looks like what I want in what looks like TFS: http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/slange/WindowsLiveWriter/QuickWaytoIntegratePhpEDandTeamFoundatio_96B5/image_thumb_8.png. Have yet to be able to create a project in TFS to test it myself :).

Comment: Answer to my second question can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181409%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, the Pending Changes window (or `tf status` command) shows you all the local changes on your PC. You can include or exclude changes to decide what you want to check in, and then check in just those changes. Or undo changes if you wish to revert and discard your changes. You can also set permissions on individual folders/files (for users or groups) to prevent them being checked out or in, so you can protect areas of your source control tree form being accidentally modified, or modified by unauthorised people.